# Using Replace within html actionlink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, actionlink

I have an application in MVC5/C#

My index view is a simple list from a model.   I added an additional html actionlink to view the history of any selected item.  With this link, I am going to a different controller (ICS_HistoryView) and passing an id parameter.

Originally it broke because some of the items (Old_ItemID field) have / in them, causing the link to break.   So, after some research, I learned that I can use Replace to replace / with -, so the url will not break and then switch it back in the controller of the new view.   However, I am getting a null error when the view loads, on this line

```
@Html.ActionLink("History", "History", "ICS_HistoryView", new { id = item.Old_ItemID.Replace('/', '-')}, null)
```

But, without the Replace, it loads properly.  Only when I click the History link, does the url break with the / in the parameter.

```
@Html.ActionLink("History", "History", "ICS_HistoryView", new { id = item.Old_ItemID}, null)
```

Can someone help me understand why it becomes null when I use replace and breaks the code?

I can provide the controller code if needed, but it's really simple.  This is just a list view.

Example:

Old_ItemID = VNC/2/1

Without the Replace, I get the correct url with parameter VNC/2/1 but I get page not found, obviousl

Adding Replace, I get a null error - and I don't understand why

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("History", "History", "ICS_HistoryView", new { id = item.Old_ItemID?.Replace('/', '-')}, null)`  try this once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason I suspect for this error is when `item.Old_ItemID` is `null`.
Otherwise it works fine for string with any value including empty string.
Could you try adding null-condition operator like `item.Old_ItemID?.Replace("/","-")`

For best practice, I would suggest such manipulations in Model/Domain classes.
Create a Get property or a method in `Item (or whatever class that is)` to replace tokens in URL.
i.e.

```cs
public string OldItemIdForUrlGeneration => this.Old_ItemID.Replace("/", "-");
```

and then

```
@Html.ActionLink("History", "History", "ICS_HistoryView", new { id = item.OldItemIdForUrlGeneration }, null)
```